# OSGi bundle has name unknown_0.0.0

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I have created OSGi bundle by Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin. Output jar file seems good, and MANIFEST.MF is following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: cz.bach.entities.ui.extensions;uses:="org.osgi.framewo
rk,cz.bach.entities.ui.extensions.output,org.slf4j,cz.bach.dataframe2
.domain,com.vaadin.ui,cz.bach.entities.ui.commons,cz.bach.entities.ui
.actions,com.vaadin.server,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotati
on,cz.bach.entities.ui.lang,cz.bach.entities.ui.output,org.aspectj.la
ng,org.springframework.transaction.aspectj,org.aspectj.lang.reflect,o
rg.springframework.transaction.annotation,org.aspectj.runtime.reflect
,org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj,org.springframework.beans,
org.springframework.context,org.springframework.beans.factory.config,
com.vaadin.event,org.apache.log4j,org.osgi.framework.launch"
Ignore-Package: cz.bach.entities.ui.extensions
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Built-By: firzen
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Name: extensions
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Bnd-LastModified: 1446557486350
Bundle-Activator: cz.bach.entities.ui.extensions.Activator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: isai-extensions
Import-Package: com.vaadin.event;resolution:=optional;version="7.5",co
m.vaadin.server;resolution:=optional;version="7.5",com.vaadin.ui;reso
lution:=optional;version="7.5",cz.bach.dataframe2.domain;resolution:=
optional,cz.bach.entities.ui.actions;resolution:=optional,cz.bach.ent
ities.ui.commons;resolution:=optional,cz.bach.entities.ui.extensions.
output;resolution:=optional,cz.bach.entities.ui.lang;resolution:=opti
onal,cz.bach.entities.ui.output;resolution:=optional,org.apache.log4j
;resolution:=optional,org.aspectj.lang;resolution:=optional,org.aspec
tj.lang.reflect;resolution:=optional,org.aspectj.runtime.reflect;reso
lution:=optional,org.osgi.framework;resolution:=optional;version="1.3
",org.osgi.framework.launch;resolution:=optional;version="1.1",org.sl
f4j;resolution:=optional;version="1.7",org.springframework.beans;reso
lution:=optional;version="3.1",org.springframework.beans.factory.anno
tation;resolution:=optional;version="3.1",org.springframework.beans.f
actory.aspectj;resolution:=optional;version="3.1",org.springframework
.beans.factory.config;resolution:=optional;version="3.1",org.springfr
amework.context;resolution:=optional;version="3.1",org.springframewor
k.transaction.annotation;resolution:=optional;version="3.1",org.sprin
gframework.transaction.aspectj;resolution:=optional;version="3.1"
```

But when I load this jar file by this code in my project ..

```
public void installPackage(File f) throws BundleException  {
    Bundle b = ctx.installBundle("file:" + f.getPath());
    System.out.println("starting bundle: " + b + ", location: " + f.getPath());
    b.start();
}
```

.. the output is:

```
starting bundle: unknown_0.0.0 [3], location: /tmp/isai-extensions.jar
```

It means that symbolic name of bundle is `null` despite the fact that it was specified in MANIFEST.MF by line: `Bundle-SymbolicName: isai-extensions`. Also when I call `b.start()`, no exception is thrown. It is quite strange behaviour.. How can I set symbolic name properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by removing `/tmp/org.eclipse.osgi` folder (on GNU/Linux machine). After that step my bundle started to work.

Comment: I don't know it exactly - you are OSGi master here :-)  But in mentioned folder I have found some folders which obviously represents bundles, and probably my bundle wasn't properly updated when I redeployed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Bundle.getSymbolicName`.

In your example code you are calling `Bundle.toString`. The OSGi spec doesn't define exactly what this method should return, but I am a bit surprised that it's returning "unknown".

Comment: That's unexpected. I suspect that the bundle has not really installed properly. Are you absolutely sure that your code throws no exception? Can you wrap it with a `try{ .. } catch (Throwable)` to be sure?

Comment: One thing that looks odd is your way of turning the file into a URL. Just prefixing with `file:` is not safe, it will fail if the file path is relative or if you run on Windows. You should use `f.toURI().toString()` instead. Also when you report the location of the bundle you should use `b.getLocation()`.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Finally I solved this by completely different way - look at my solution.